# Get same div level but different class name with jsoup

Tags: html, loops, jsoup

I would like to get data from html

```
<div class="xyz">
    <div class="opq">
        <div class="one">One</div></div>
    <div class="rst">
        <div class="vwu">
            <div class="alpha"><a href="a">A</a></div></div></div>
    <div class="opq">
        <div class="one">Two</div> 
    <div class="rst">
        <div class="vwu">
            <div class="alpha"><a href="b">B</a></div></div></div>
    <div class="rst">
        <div class="vwu">
            <div class="alpha"><a href="c">C</a></div></div></div>
    <div class="opq">
        <div class="one">Three</div></div>
    <div class="rst">
        <div class="vwu">
            <div class="alpha"><a href="d">D</a></div></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How i can get the data in new format, where A is child of One, Two is parents of B and C, and so D is parents of D. When i try use loop for ( element) i just get all of component. I have trouble to get element between One - Two - Three. There only one element (A) between "One" dan "Two". Next, 2 element (B & C) between "One" and "Two". The Last one is only 1 element, D, after "Three". 
And i will show like :

```
One :
> A
Two :
> B
> C
Three :
> D
```

I use eq(0) to access them, but the result show false output.

To do that i'm simply doing this:

```
Elements ht = dok.select("div.one");
Elements li = dok.select("div.alpha:eq(0)");

    for(Element el : ht   ){
      System.out.println(el.ownText()+" : "+li.get(i).text());
      i++;
      }
```

But the result was:

```
One :
> A
Two :
> B
Three :
> C
```

based on the result, isn't like what i hope. That's it between "Two" and "Three" actually have 2 element, B and C. While the last "Three" it must have element of D. But in this result , the element D is can't display.
Thanks for any advice

Comment: Will see if I can put something together.